# Accessing nodal and degree of freedom organisation in the solution vector in Fenics and Firedrake

Tags: finite-element, fenics

**Context**

Let suppose a solution to a finite element problem (associated to a mesh) stored in a vector $X$  of size $(N \cdot d)$ corresponding to $N$ nodes in the mesh and $d$ degrees of freedom for each node.

This vector could be organised this way :

$X = (X_1^1, \ldots, X_1^d, X_2^1, \ldots, X_2^d,\mathbf{\cdots}, X_N^1,\ldots,X_N^d)$

i.e for every node, we concatenate every dofs evolution, then we iterate for every node...

However, as Fenics or Firedrake optimise their computation cost using sparse mass and stifness matrices, the final organisation of the solution might not be structured as simply as it is in this example.

**Needs**

For a project, I need to isolate the evolution of the first dof of each nodes (in my case, it will permite plotting the temporal displacements of a plate).

**Question**

How do you access the organisation of nodes and dofs in the solution vector, so I can isolate only the first dof evolutions, with Fenics and/or Firedrake ?

Comment: Framing question -- can you elaborate on what you're trying to plot? There might be an easier way to do that without having to manually pull out degrees of freedom.

Comment: This is a question very specific to one software package. You're probably going to get better answers by asking on the forums for that software -- that's where all of the people who know the answer hang out.

Comment: @DanielShapero I'm sure there is an easier way but I'm using fenics only to pull out mass and stifness matrices. The solution vector is computed with my own integration scheme. To be more precise, I want to know how my mass matrix is organised because it is used in an matrix equation from which I compute the solution vector X so it's organisation relates on the one of the mass matrix.
To resume, for what I am doing, I'm obliged to pull out the degrees of freedom manually.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for your answer, I will post on Fenics forum!

Comment: There might be other Python packages better suited for this purpose. The ones you mention are pretty black box at linear algebra level. That is, if you really just need the stiffness and mass matrices for a specific weak formulation, and information how the DOFs are ordered, and use your own time-integration scheme.

Comment: @knl That might be a solution indeed. I'm gonna look for that. The reason I used Fenics (and Firedrake) is because the assembly of complex elements such as HHJ or Bell elements is quite hard to do by hand.
I hope you're right and that I'm gonna find another library to assemble with a good knowledge of DOFS compatible with such elements but I have some doubts...

Comment: Bell triangle somehow defies understanding but I just made a PR implementing HHJ to my own code together with an example in case you want to test it: https://github.com/kinnala/scikit-fem/pull/1027